# Pass callback with parameters to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am asking something that is probably trivial but that has been bugging me for a while.

Lets say we have a CHILD component that renders some buttons:

```
const Picker = ({ data, label, visible, cancelCallback, onPressCallback }) => {

  function renderRow (data) {
    return data.map((el) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={listViewItemContainer} 
          key={el.label}
          onPress={}
        >
          <Text style={listViewItem}> { el.label } </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      animationType="fade"
      onRequestClose={() => {}}
      transparent={true}
    >


          <View style={listViewContainerStyle}>
            { renderRow(data) }
          </View>


    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Now when I press one of those buttons I want to make a callback to the parent BUT I want to pass some parameters like the label of the element pressed. Something like:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={listViewItemContainer} 
  key={el.label}
  onPress={onPressCallback(el.label)} // onPressCallback is a Prop passed to the child
>
  <Text style={listViewItem}> { el.label } </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And then handle the logic in the parent component.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this.

```
   onPress={() => onPressCallback(el.label)}
```